# ADO.net Entities postback Gridview datasource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I am trying to bind an ADO entity query to a gridview, but each event that the gridview fires causes the page to postback.  Every time the page posts back, the datasource is null and I have to bind the query again.

All the code works find for displaying and editing the data, except for the rowupdating event.

My problem lies in that when the rowupdating event fires, the page does a post back and I have to bind the data again loosing the selected values that I wanted to update the database with.  If I don't bind the data again, the datasource is null and my .findcontrol returns an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

I test the rest of the code in the rowupdating event by:

1) Setting a breakpoint on the rowupdating event

2) clicking the update hyperlink

3) Changing the data in the table using SQL Server Management Studio

4) continuing code execution

5) Re-executing the Query in SQL SMS

After this the data in the table was updated to the old values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HCA_QualityModel;


public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static HCA_QualityEntities database = new HCA_QualityEntities();
    static object grvMachinesQuery = (from m in database.Machines
                                      from d in database.Workcenters
                                      where m.WorkcenterFK == d.id
                                      select
                                          new { id = m.id, MachineName = m.MachineName, WorkCenterFK = d.WorkCenterName });
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bind the gridview on intial page load
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) bindGridViewData();
    }
    protected void bindGridViewData()
    {
        //Data binds for gridviews and ddl's

        grvMachines.DataSource = grvMachinesQuery;
        grvWorkCenters.DataSource = (from w in database.Workcenters select w);
        grvUsers.DataSource = (from u in database.Users select u);
        ddlAddDept.DataSource = grvWorkCenters.DataSource;
        ddlAddDept.DataValueField = "id";
        ddlAddDept.DataTextField = "WorkCenterName";
        DataBind();
    }
    //Adds new data to the db, then rebinds the griviews to the db
    #region Submit Buttons
    protected void btnSubmitMachine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add new machine to the database

        Machine temp = new Machine();
        temp.MachineName = txtAddMachine.Text;
        temp.WorkcenterFK = Int32.Parse(ddlAddDept.SelectedValue);
        database.Machines.AddObject(temp);
        database.SaveChanges();
        bindGridViewData();

    }
    protected void btnSubmitDept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add new workcenter to database

        Workcenter temp = new Workcenter();
        temp.WorkCenterName = txtAddDept.Text;
        database.Workcenters.AddObject(temp);
        database.SaveChanges();
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    protected void btnUserSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add new user to the database

        HCA_QualityModel.User temp = new User();
        temp.Username = txtAddUser.Text;
        temp.Password = txtAddPassword.Text;
        database.Users.AddObject(temp);
        database.SaveChanges();
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    #endregion
    //Handles Updating, editing, and deleting Gridview Controls
    #region Gridview machines
    protected void grvMachines_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList temp = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlDept"));
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.DataSource = (from w in database.Workcenters select w);
            temp.DataTextField = "WorkCenterName";
            temp.DataValueField = "id";
            temp.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void grvMachines_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int id = Int32.Parse(((Label)grvMachines.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId") as Label).Text);
        database.Machines.DeleteObject(((Machine)(from m in database.Machines where m.id == id select m).Single()));
        database.SaveChanges();
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    protected void grvMachines_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {

        grvMachines.EditIndex = -1;
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    protected void grvMachines_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grvMachines.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    protected void grvMachines_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


        //Gridviews have no data on postback from events, rebinding looses the selected values from edit mode.

        bindGridViewData();

        DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlDept");
        TextBox name = (TextBox)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("txtMachine");
        Int32 id = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("lblId")).Text));

        //Working Code to update the database, recieving incorrect data from controls due to rebinding 
        HCA_QualityEntities database = new HCA_QualityEntities();
        Machine temp = (from m in database.Machines where m.id == id select m).First();
        temp.MachineName = (name.Text);
        temp.WorkcenterFK = Int32.Parse(dept.SelectedValue);
        database.SaveChanges();
        grvMachines.EditIndex = -1;
        bindGridViewData();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Asp code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
      <table style="width:800px; vertical-align:top;">
        <tr style="width:800px;">
           <td style="width:230px; height:90px;">
                Add New Machine:
                <br />
                &nbsp;Machine&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dept
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddMachine" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddDept" runat="server" Width="110px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitMachine" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnSubmitMachine_Click" />
           </td>
           <td style="width:190px; height:90px;">
                Add New Dept:
                <br />
                Dept Name
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDept" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitDept" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnSubmitDept_Click" />
           </td>
           <td style="width:250px; height:90px;"> 
                Add New User:
                <br />
                &nbsp;Username&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddUser" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddPassword" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUserSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                onclick="btnUserSubmit_Click" />
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:800px; vertical-align:top;">
           <td style="width:230px;">
                <asp:GridView ID="grvMachines" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    Width="230px" onrowdeleting="grvMachines_RowDeleting" 
                    onrowediting="grvMachines_RowEditing" 
                    onrowcancelingedit="grvMachines_RowCancelingEdit" 
                    onrowupdating="grvMachines_RowUpdating" 
                    onrowdatabound="grvMachines_RowDataBound" 
                    EnableViewState="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMachine" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MachineName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMachine" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MachineName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="50px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDept" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkcenterFK") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldept" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="120px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Actions" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="True"
                            ControlStyle-Width="50px" CausesValidation="False" >
                        </asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
           </td>
           <td style="width:170px;">
                <asp:GridView ID="grvWorkCenters" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    Width="170px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WorkCenter">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWorkcenter" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkCenterName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWorkcenter" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkCenterName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="75px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Actions" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                            ControlStyle-Width="50px" CausesValidation="False" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
           </td>
           <td style="width:290px;"> 
                <asp:GridView ID="grvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    Width="290px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="120px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ControlStyle Width="120px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Actions" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true"
                        ControlStyle-Width="50px" CausesValidation="false" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your source code, now it should work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HCA_QualityModel;


public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
static HCA_QualityEntities database = new HCA_QualityEntities();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bind the gridview on intial page load
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) bindGridViewData();
}
protected void bindGridViewData()
{

 static object grvMachinesQuery = (from m in database.Machines
                                  from d in database.Workcenters
                                  where m.WorkcenterFK == d.id
                                  select
                                      new { id = m.id, MachineName = m.MachineName,  WorkCenterFK = d.WorkCenterName });

    //Data binds for gridviews and ddl's

    grvMachines.DataSource = grvMachinesQuery;
    grvWorkCenters.DataSource = (from w in database.Workcenters select w);
    grvUsers.DataSource = (from u in database.Users select u);
    ddlAddDept.DataSource = grvWorkCenters.DataSource;
    ddlAddDept.DataValueField = "id";
    ddlAddDept.DataTextField = "WorkCenterName";
    DataBind();
}

//Adds new data to the db, then rebinds the griviews to the db
#region Submit Buttons
protected void btnSubmitMachine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add new machine to the database

    Machine temp = new Machine();
    temp.MachineName = txtAddMachine.Text;
    temp.WorkcenterFK = Int32.Parse(ddlAddDept.SelectedValue);
    database.Machines.AddObject(temp);
    database.SaveChanges();
    bindGridViewData();

}
protected void btnSubmitDept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add new workcenter to database

    Workcenter temp = new Workcenter();
    temp.WorkCenterName = txtAddDept.Text;
    database.Workcenters.AddObject(temp);
    database.SaveChanges();
    bindGridViewData();
}
protected void btnUserSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add new user to the database

    HCA_QualityModel.User temp = new User();
    temp.Username = txtAddUser.Text;
    temp.Password = txtAddPassword.Text;
    database.Users.AddObject(temp);
    database.SaveChanges();
    bindGridViewData();
}
#endregion
//Handles Updating, editing, and deleting Gridview Controls
#region Gridview machines
protected void grvMachines_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList temp = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlDept"));
    if (temp != null)
    {
        temp.DataSource = (from w in database.Workcenters select w);
        temp.DataTextField = "WorkCenterName";
        temp.DataValueField = "id";
        temp.DataBind();
    }

}
protected void grvMachines_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    int id = Int32.Parse(((Label)grvMachines.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId") as Label).Text);
    database.Machines.DeleteObject(((Machine)(from m in database.Machines where m.id == id select m).Single()));
    database.SaveChanges();
    bindGridViewData();
}
protected void grvMachines_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{

    grvMachines.EditIndex = -1;
    bindGridViewData();
}
protected void grvMachines_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grvMachines.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    bindGridViewData();
}
protected void grvMachines_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{


    //Gridviews have no data on postback from events, rebinding looses the selected values from edit mode.

    bindGridViewData();

    DropDownList dept = (DropDownList)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlDept");
    TextBox name = (TextBox)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("txtMachine");
    Int32 id = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)grvMachines.Rows[grvMachines.EditIndex].FindControl("lblId")).Text));

    //Working Code to update the database, recieving incorrect data from controls due to rebinding 
    HCA_QualityEntities database = new HCA_QualityEntities();
    Machine temp = (from m in database.Machines where m.id == id select m).First();
    temp.MachineName = (name.Text);
    temp.WorkcenterFK = Int32.Parse(dept.SelectedValue);
    database.SaveChanges();
    grvMachines.EditIndex = -1;
    bindGridViewData();
}
#endregion
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i'm afraid refactoring did not help.

  I stll have to call the bindgridviewdata() at the beginning of the rowupdating event, which then updates the database with the old values not the ones the user changed in edit mode.  If I do not call bindgridviewdata() at the start of the rowupdating event, I continue to the argumentoutofrange exception.

Answer (score 1):

Can you disconnect the event handler temporarily?

```
myGridView.rowUpdating -= myGridView_rowUpdating;
//code to populate
myGridView.rowUpdating += myGridView_rowupdating;
```

Or [C# Disable Event Handler Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288195/c-sharp-disable-event-handler-problem)

I had a wonky validation block I was attempting to refactor for a job where my dataBindings were refreshing when I didn't want them to and causing them to rebind, and then rebind then I ended up in this recursive-y soup. I only had one instance so I just took the event handler off and put it back on.

Comment: Not sure where to put this, 

The problem isn't that the gridview is randomly refreshing my databinds, I am refreshing them manually because there is no datasource to access when the rowupdating event fires.